# Regex or operator

Tags: regex

I'm having kind of a noobish problem with the or operator

I want to look for

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

Followed by

```
\-[a-zA-Z]?
```

or

```
\'[a-zA-Z]?
```

Essentially grab any word, so I can leave out:
spaces, `\t`, `\n`, `\n\r` etc. I understand also that `\w` would be nice to use, but I don't want things like `9-10` as a result, I'm looking purely for words.

I get that `(thing|thing2)` is the syntax for or, but it's just then capturing the whole word, then as a second match, the latter part of contractions and hyphenated words.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So what's your question? You want to capture the whole word? (also, your hyphenated word regex only captures the first letter after the hyphen?)

Comment: I got it:
([a-zA-Z]+(?:\-?[a-zA-Z]+|\'?[a-zA-Z]*))

Answer (score 2):

You can use a character class for this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[-\'][a-zA-Z]+
```

Or, if you really want to use the `or` operator, you can just use a non-capturing group `(?:)`:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:-|\')[a-zA-Z]+
```